# Unsupport Orientation in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

My app is totally work only on portrait mode, but I have only one UIViewController that needs to be only in landscape mode in iOS6.

So:

- One UIViewController should only support landscape mode.
- The others UIViewController should only support portrait mode.

If I change on `supported Interface Orientations` to support both modes, I can't prevent them from rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is (I assume) that you are using a UINavigationController interface. iOS doesn't support forcing different view controllers in a navigation interface into different orientations.

Indeed, the individual view controllers are not even consulted. You have to subclass UINavigationController itself and have it dictate the orientation.

But even then you won't be able to force rotation when changing view controllers. The only way to do that is with a presented view controller.

This has been explained many, many, *many* times here on Stack Overflow. Please search before posting.

Comment: @markaraujo this is the best way… :) also, you can check my example http://stackoverflow.com/a/16481921/1702413

Comment: @TonyMkenu, it is exactly what I need, could you create an example to work without storyboard? and post here as the correct question, many thx

Comment: @marckarauujo  The Matt's answer.. Is the correct answer. For xib is the same thinks, just copy some code from my example

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, on each individual view controller implement `supportedInterfaceOrientation` and only pass `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` to all your view controllers except the one you want rotated

Comment: I already did it and doesn't work, it still rotate to both mode.

Comment: implement 'preferredInterfaceOrientation' also then.

Comment: thx Clint, but also doesn't work, have you tried yourself?

Comment: A couple months ago I had to figure this problem out. It's kinda fuzzy in my memory how I solved it, but I know those two methods have a big part in getting it to work

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551247/autorotate-a-single-uiviewcontroller-in-ios-6-with-uitabbar

Comment: this only works if you want to let only one UIViewController to be in portrait mode and the except one to be in both modes, portrait and landscape.