# iOS6 Orientation with NavigationController

Tags: ios6, uinavigationcontroller, orientation, pushviewcontroller, autorotate

I am developing an application that has several views and a root view controller. It's based on UINavigationController using pushViewController: 
In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
BIDLoginController *loginController = [[BIDLoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginController];
[self.window setRootViewController:self.navController];
```

In loginController:

```
BIDMainPageController *mainPageController = [[BIDMainPageController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainPage" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainPageController animated:YES];
```

but the view controllers are subclasses of UIViewController, not UINavigationController. Now I want some of the views to support orientation(portrait and landscape) and some of them only support portrait. I have tried the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

It doesn't work. shouldAutorotate: method never been called. I have tried UINavigationControllerDelegate with no result either. When I change these view controllers' super class from UIViewController to UINavigationController, the view doesn't show up, only a navigation bar is shown. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsupport Orientation in iOS6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469651/unsupport-orientation-in-ios6)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you are describing. iOS 6 doesn't support *forcing* different child view controllers of a UINavigationController to rotate. They can *respond* differently to device rotation, but they cannot be *forced* to rotate.