# How to force Interface Orientation rotation?

Tags: iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm working on an iPhone app that supports portrait only. But while seeing some pages it would be great to rotate to better visualize it.

The problem is when you go back to the previous page, the interface orientation remains on landscape until you manually rotate your device.

It's hard to explain, but what I want to do is something similar to the FaceBook app. While looking at pictures you can rotate the device. When you tap "Done" and go back to the previous page, the orientation changes to portrait, even thought the device still is on landscape position. It forces the orientation change.

Anyone has any idea how to do this?

Comment: The thing is, this has been asked about a zillion times on Stack Overflow - and has been answered correctly. Please search before you post.

Comment: Not very constructive, but if I were developing the app, I would find a behaviour that not only forces the user to have one or another device orientation but has its rules change depending on the page they're viewing... very user-unfriendly and anti-ergonomic. If I were you, I would make the app work in both orientations all the time.

Comment: I did search, all it showed up was a 2010 thread with no answer. But looks like there is more out there. Thanks.

Comment: Also you could read my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_rotation_of_a_presented_view

Comment: check my answer (with example) - you can thank me there :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/16481921/1702413