# IOS 6 Storyboard rotation doesn't work as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, storyboard, navigationcontroller

I'm developing an iOS6 App with storyboards and i'm encountering an unexpected beahviour.
My app is almost in portrait mode , and i would keep this orientation in all the views except two.For this reason the project supports both landscape and portrait mode, i've subclassed navigation controller with a category (as explained almost everywhere :-)in Appdelegate.m  and every view controller implements

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; (landscape where needed)
}
```

and

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
return YES;
}
```

Everything seems to work well except the fact that in the transition between a landscape view to a portrait one (not vice versa ?) , all the elements of the ui are displayed in landscape(imagine that you're keeping the phone horizontal), if you turn the phone , the rotation event is fired, the ui turns back in portrait and only now is locked to this orientation.Is there a way to fire the rotation BEFORE the view is presented?
Why the shouldAutorotate is not called at the ViewWillAppear stage?

Thank you!

Comment: check my answer ... and my example.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16481921/1702413

Answer (score 0):

Remove both the above function and try this it should work

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
         Return YES for supported orientations

    }
```

if still it's not working then try this change the appDelegate

```
[window addSubview:nav.view];
```

to this code

```
 window.rootViewController=nav;
```

Comment: I've removed the functions and the definitions in AppDelegate.m but this function is never called and the ui is not locked to the desired orientations.

Answer (score 0):

I found this online chapter very good for explaining UIViewControllers and rotation.

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#Rotation

It s a big page, scroll down to Rotation.